# Conditions for an Language to be infinite

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

given 'r' , a regular expression that does not include λ or ∅, What are the Conditions of 'r' so that L(r) would be infinite?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions correspond to a simple recursive definition, which starts with the symbols from some alphabet and extends them with applications of three operators: alternation, concatenation and Kleene closure.

So ask yourself: Which of these operators can produce an infinite set?

---

Formal definition:

Let $\Sigma$ be a finite set of symbols. Then the set of regular expressions $R_\Sigma$ is the smallest set of expressions which can be constructed using these rules:

- Every $c \in \Sigma$ is in $R_\Sigma$.
- $\lambda$ and $\emptyset$ are in $R_\Sigma$.
- If $r$ and $s$ are regular expressions over the alphabet $\Sigma$ then so are:

  - $(r+s)$
  - $(rs)$
  - $(r^*)$

A standard proof technique for properties of regular expressions is to apply mathematical induction to this definition.